# LWJGL won't give me an OpenGL context that supports 4.1

Tags: macos, opengl, lwjgl

I'm making a game on OS X using LWJGL, and I've read that OS X does not support compatibility profiles, and that, by default, any context I create will support only version 2.1 or older. I want to use more modern stuff, so I'm trying to get a 4.1 context working (4.1 is the latest version supported by my computer, according to Apple).

As far as I know, the way to request a certain version of OpenGL in LWJGL is to pass a `ContextAttribs(major_version, minor_version)` to `Display.create()` like so:

```
  Display.create(new PixelFormat(), new ContextAttribs(4, 1));
```

I decided to test that this was working by putting a `#version 410` statement in my vertex shader, but alas, when I query the "shader info log" I get the error message:

```
ERROR: 0:1: '' :  version '410' is not supported
```

I really don't know what to do at this point. I know that my graphics card supports OpenGL 4.1, and I am requesting a 4.1 context from LWJGL, but apparently it won't give me one. Is there something else that needs to be done to support this?

Comment: Which version of OS X do you use? OpenGL-4 support has been added only with Maverricks.

Comment: @datenwolf I'm using Yosemite.

Comment: I don't know LWJGL, but OS X has IMHO _just_ a 3.2 Corepofile with forward compatibility. So I would guess it needs to be something like `ContextAttribs conAttrib = new ContextAttribs(3, 2); conAttrib.withProfileCore(true); conAttrib.withForwardCompatible(true);` to get `3.2+` and therefore `4.1` if supported. but I can't test it. At least in with the C-API you set the `3_2_CORE` to get the `4.1`.

Comment: @t.niese I tested it for you. `version '320' is not supported`. I think it must be something else.

Comment: @anthropomorphic there is no shader version `320`, it is called `150`. With 3.3 there shader versions where _synchronized_  look like the OpenGL version `330`. Please check if it accepts `410`.

Comment: Oh, right, I forgot about that. Is it `#version 1.50` or `#version 150`?

Comment: It's 150 (for the sake of the directive) ;) Version numbers are integers.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman Yes sorry. I corrected it. It was to long ago that I used 150 :D

Comment: Anyway as LWJGL uses the C API internally it should work the same as in c. So if you successfully switched to the core profile in OS X you should be able to use `#version 410` so leave that version instead of trying `#version 150` even if the core profile is called 3.2 ;)

Comment: @t.niese `410` also throws an error. Also, no matter what I pass to my `ContextAttribs` `#version 120` works in the shader. This tells me that my `ContextAttribs` is not causing the OpenGL version to change at all, because if it were, `120` would not be supported when I requested a version higher than `2.1`.

Comment: @anthropomorphic: To be clear, you have tried this: `Display.create(new PixelFormat(), new ContextAttribs(3, 2).withProfileCore(true).withForwardCompatible(true));`?

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman actually I only just figured that out like 2 minutes ago. And now that I've removed like 8 deprecated calls, it is working. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

So apparently the necessary LWJGL call to generate an OpenGL 4.1 context is as follows.

```
Display.create(new PixelFormat(), new ContextAttribs(3, 2).withForwardCompatible(true).withProfileCore(true));
```

**Note:** it *must* be `ContextAttribs(3, 2)`, **not** `(4, 1)`. I assume this is due to some oddity with Apple's OpenGL support. <del>Apparently they don't really support OpenGL 4.1, they support 3.2 with forward compatibility to 4.1. Dumb, I know.</del> **Edit:** *this is not totally true. See the comments for details.*

I found this page helpful in figuring all this out: [LWJGL Version Selection](http://www.lwjgl.org/wiki/index.php?title=Version_selection)

Comment: Strange that it is not mentioned in the [wiki](http://www.lwjgl.org/wiki/index.php?title=Version_selection). But I right now saw that it is mentioned here : [lwjgl: ContextAttribs](http://www.lwjgl.org/javadoc/org/lwjgl/opengl/ContextAttribs.html). Not the best docs. Well they fully support 4.1 in 10.10, why the don't call it that way somehow strange :D

Comment: @t.niese I added a link to the doc I found. It had no mention of the weird *Version 3.2 with forward compatibility = pseudo 4.1 on OS X* thing, but it did explain how to generate a context with a specific version. I had originally only found the `ContextAttribs` doc that you just linked, and therefore didn't know about the necessary calls you had to make in addition to specifying the version number.

Comment: @t.niese Thanks to you and Andon M. Coleman for pointing out the version number weirdness.

Comment: It's not that OS X does not support OpenGL 4.1, the real problem boils down to a silly decision they made when they implemented core profiles. They use a constant: `kCGLOGLPVersion_3_2_Core` to mean ***any*** core profile. That constant really should not include a version number, but unfortunately it does. Other platforms actually have facilities to let you explicitly request a GL context version (not just a profile), but Apple does not. If I were the author of the framework, I wouldn't take Apple's constant so literally, but many frameworks do.

Comment: version derictive in shaders do support up to 410 though. That was the case also when 3.2 core arrived.